# Rock, Paper, Scissors - Python(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have this little project of Rock, Paper and Scissors for learning (specifically using Tkinter to create a GUI) and I'm stuck with a counter. I have already checked in Python terminal that the counter is working, but it's not updating the Label so the counter is stuck in 0 in the interface. I tried everything and searched for other programs like mine and they did the same thing, I simply don't know what to do. Could anyone solve that for me? (The code is a little over extensive, sorry for that. Also some texts are in portuguese, but I think it doesn't really matter.)

```
from tkinter import
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

counterv = 0 #**
counterd = 0 #**

# Inicialization
root = Tk()
root.title('Pedra, Papel, Tesoura')
root.iconbitmap('c:/imagens/pedraico.ico')

# Bot List
lista_ppt = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura']

# Comandos externos

counterv_label = Label(root, text=f'Vitórias: **{counterv}** ', bg='blue', anchor=W)
counterd_label = Label(root, text=f'Derrota: **{counterd}** ', bg='red', anchor=E)

# Creating images
inicio_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/ppt_imagem.png'))

pedra_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/pedra_.png'))
papel_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/papel_.png'))
tesoura_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/tesoura_.png'))

pedrabot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/pedrabot.png'))
papelbot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/papelbot.png'))
tesourabot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/tesourabot.png'))

# Creating labels
pedra_tela = Label(image=pedra_img)
papel_tela = Label(image=papel_img)
tesoura_tela = Label(image=tesoura_img)

pedrabot_tela = Label(image=pedrabot_img)
papelbot_tela = Label(image=papelbot_img)
tesourabot_tela = Label(image=tesourabot_img)

empate = Label(root, text='Empate')
vitoria = Label(root, text='Vitória.')
derrota = Label(root, text='Derrota')

imagem_inicial = Label(image=inicio_img)

indicador = Label(root, text='<- Você - - Bot ->')

# Defining


def b_pedra():
    global bot
    global counterv #**
    global counterd #**

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedrabot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1 #**
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1 #**

    counterv_label.grid_forget() #**
    counterd_label.grid_forget()
    counterv_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
    counterd_label.grid(row=4, column=2)


def b_papel():
    global bot
    global counterv #**
    global counterd #**

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1 #**
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papelbot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1 #**

    counterv_label.grid_forget() #**
    counterd_label.grid_forget()
    counterv_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
    counterd_label.grid(row=4, column=2)


def b_tesoura():
    global bot
    global counterv #**
    global counterd #**

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1 #**
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1 #**
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesourabot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

    counterv_label.grid_forget() #**
    counterd_label.grid_forget()
    counterv_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
    counter_label.grid(row=4, column=2)

# Buttons

pedra = Button(root, text='Pedra', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_pedra)
papel = Button(root, text='Papel', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_papel)
tesoura = Button(root, text='Tesoura', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_tesoura)

pedra.grid(row=2, column=0)
papel.grid(row=2, column=1)
tesoura.grid(row=2, column=2)

imagem_inicial.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: These asterisks are to show where I put the counter

Comment: You need to update the text in the labels after every update of the counters.

Comment: I suggest you to remove the asterisks that you have put and rather have them as a comment, because it's irritating to remove them for testing. Second, I don't see where you have defined `counter_label` in your code, please update the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The reason for the labels not getting updated is that they have been been been given fixed values at the time of initialization. To update the values of the labels you have a couple of options:

1. Attach a `textvariable` to the label and update the value of the same later, as already mentioned by @Mahendra Suthar or use the `.update()` method on to the labels.
2. You can use the `.configure` method to set the value of the text by using `label.configure(text = 'Updated_text')` or `label['text'] = 'Updated_text'`.

Here is the working sample of your code (I have changed the images to text due to unavailability of the same)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

counterv = 0
counterd = 0

# Inicialization
root = Tk()
root.title('Pedra, Papel, Tesoura')
#root.iconbitmap('c:/imagens/pedraico.ico')

# Bot List
lista_ppt = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura']

# Comandos externos

counterv_label = Label(root, text = f'Vitórias: {counterv} ', bg='blue', anchor=W)
counterd_label = Label(root, text = f'Derrota: {counterd} ', bg='red', anchor=E)
counterv_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
counterd_label.grid(row=4, column=2)
'''
# Creating images
inicio_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/ppt_imagem.png'))

pedra_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/pedra_.png'))
papel_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/papel_.png'))
tesoura_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/tesoura_.png'))

pedrabot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/pedrabot.png'))
papelbot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/papelbot.png'))
tesourabot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c:/imagens/tesourabot.png'))
'''
# Creating labels
pedra_tela = Label(text = 'Pedra')
papel_tela = Label(text = 'Papel')
tesoura_tela = Label(text = 'Tesoura')

pedrabot_tela = Label(text = 'Pedra Bot')
papelbot_tela = Label(text = 'Papel Bot')
tesourabot_tela = Label(text = 'Tesoura Bot')

empate = Label(root, text='Empate')
vitoria = Label(root, text='Vitória.')
derrota = Label(root, text='Derrota')

imagem_inicial = Label(text='Inicio')

indicador = Label(root, text='<- Você - - Bot ->')

# Defining


def b_pedra():
    global bot
    global counterv
    global counterd

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedrabot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1

    counterv_label.configure(text = f'Vitórias: {counterv} ')
    counterd_label.configure(text = f'Derrota: {counterd} ')


def b_papel():
    global bot
    global counterv
    global counterd

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papelbot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1

    counterv_label.configure(text = f'Vitórias: {counterv} ')
    counterd_label.configure(text = f'Derrota: {counterd} ')

def b_tesoura():
    global bot
    global counterv
    global counterd

    bot = random.choice(lista_ppt)

    pedra_tela.grid_forget()
    papel_tela.grid_forget()
    tesoura_tela.grid_forget()

    imagem_inicial.grid_forget()

    empate.grid_forget()
    derrota.grid_forget()
    vitoria.grid_forget()

    indicador.grid_forget()
    indicador.grid(row=1, column=1)

    pedrabot_tela.grid_forget()
    papelbot_tela.grid_forget()
    tesourabot_tela.grid_forget()

    if bot == 'Pedra':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pedra_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        derrota.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterd += 1
    elif bot == 'Papel':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        papel_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        vitoria.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        counterv += 1
    elif bot == 'Tesoura':
        tesoura_tela.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tesourabot_tela.grid(row=1, column=2)
        empate.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

    counterv_label.configure(text = f'Vitórias: {counterv} ')
    counterd_label.configure(text = f'Derrota: {counterd} ')

# Buttons

pedra = Button(root, text='Pedra', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_pedra)
papel = Button(root, text='Papel', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_papel)
tesoura = Button(root, text='Tesoura', padx=40, pady=20, borderwidth=5, command=b_tesoura)

pedra.grid(row=2, column=0)
papel.grid(row=2, column=1)
tesoura.grid(row=2, column=2)

imagem_inicial.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the rookies mistakes, I've already checked and it's working perfectly. Thanks to everyone that also helped me!

Comment: @GustavoGodoy I would really appreciate if you mark this as the answer if it solved your problem, so that this question is considered as solved.  Please refer to [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry for that, first time using this site. I think I accepted as the answer. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your label is not updating because you haven't connected it to any text means it doesn't know what text to show on change.
You can use StringVar() what it does is it automatically updates label whenever text is changed.

```
counter = tk.StringVar()
counter.set("0")
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=counter)
```

so whenever counter.set is called the label automatically gets updated with new counter value.
When you initialize your label you can provide a textvariable argument that is used for text shown by label whenever it changes Tkinter automatically updates it for us.

you can read more here [how to change/update Tkinter label](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-change-the-tkinter-label-text/)

Comment: it is not necessary to attach the label with a `StringVar()`, you can also use `label.configure(text = counter)` or `label['Text'] = counter` for the same.

Comment: Thanks really much for the help!